# Error: have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? when trying to intent a class

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-manifest

Here's my code for clicking the button from my class **showInforActivity**:

```
btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(showInfoActivity.this, InformationFragment.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Whenever I click the button I got error `Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.drawerapplication/com.example.drawerapplication.ui.information.InformationFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` and it loads the previous class and layout instead of loading this
**InformationFragment** class:

```
package com.example.drawerapplication.ui.information;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.example.drawerapplication.databinding.FragmentInformationBinding;

public class InformationFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentInformationBinding binding;

    private EditText name, address, age, contact;
    private Button btnAdd, btnViewData;
    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentInformationBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        name = binding.name;
        address = binding.address;
        age = binding.age;
        contact = binding.contact;

        btnAdd = binding.add;
        btnViewData = binding.viewdata;

        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (name.length() != 0 && address.length() != 0
                && age.length() != 0 && contact.length() != 0){

                    mDatabaseHelper.addData(name.getText().toString(), address.getText().toString(),
                            age.getText().toString().trim(), Long.valueOf(contact.getText().toString().trim()));
                    toastMessages("Data Successfully Inserted!");

                }else {
                    toastMessages("Please complete all the requirements needed");
                }

            }
        });

        btnViewData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ListDataActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

    private void toastMessages(String message){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

The layout of this **InformationFragment** is **fragment_information**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.information.InformationFragment"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">
...
```

Heres my **AndroidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.drawerapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DrawerApplication">
        <activity android:name=".ui.information.ListDataActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".ui.information.showInfoActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.DrawerApplication.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried adding `InformationFragment` there however, it says `Class referenced in the manifest, com.example.drawerapplication.InformationFragment, was not found in the project or the libraries`

Please let me know what I'm missing or if you need more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use an `Intent` to start/create a `Fragment` much like you would for an `Activity`. A `Fragment` actually lives inside an `Activity` i.e. its lifecycle is bound to an `Activity`. To start a `Fragment` you have to use the `FragmentManager` that is available with the `Activity` instance

This error is coming up because Android thinks that your `InformationFragment` is an `Activity` rather than a `Fragment` and hence it is asking you if you have declared it in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file because as the rule says, you need to have each `Activity` in your app declared inside the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

So, now you can use something like [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/creating-and-using-fragments), inside your **showInfoActivity**. Technically there are many solutions available as to what you could essentially do and that's why I linked you to all possible solutions rather than just writing them here

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about this and the link is very helpful! I manage to replace the Intent line to `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()` However, it gives me an error of `No view found for id 0x7f080207 (com.example.drawerapplication:id/infoFrameLayout) for fragment InformationFragment`.

Comment: Have you declared any view with `infoFrameLayout` as the id? Also mark the answer as accepted if it helped you

Comment: I was able to get it to work. I was just calling the incorrect layout. Thank you again!

Comment: I'm glad, I could be of help!

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `Intent` for navigate to `Fragment` from a `Activity`.
For this reason you are getting this error. As, Intent receive 2 parameter `Intent(FromActivity, ToActivity.class)` . you are using fragment in 2nd parameter. We know that, when we create a activity then it it declared with `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Here, in your manifest file there are not any activity called `InformationFragment`.

You can learn Android Navigation Component to easily communicate with Activity and fragments.